# zf2 dervied controller - method seen as service

Tags: web-services, zend-framework2

i've a custom base controller ,that extend AbstractRestfulController, from which extend other controller of mine web service.

In base controller i've method like this

```
 public function p($text)
   {
      $oContainer = new Container('locale');
      $translate = $this->_oViewHelperManager->get('translate');
      return $translate($text, null, $oContainer->szLocale);
   }
```

when i work in local all work fine
my configuration is
ubuntu 14.10
php 5.5.12 as apache module

when i put it in remote server i've got

remote configuration is
php 5.5.9 as fastcgi

Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for p

p as seen like service and not like method

why?

Comment: Actually, no, `p()` is seen as an unknown method call, which gets passed to the magic `__call()` method implemented by `Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController` (and inherited by `AbstractActionController`, amongst others) see -> https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php#L287-L305

The functionality is there so that you can use `$this->somePluginName()` directly in a controller and have the magic method return the result. 
It appears that your controller doesn't have a `p()` method and you should start by looking into that.

Comment: i re upload file. now all work fine. it's very strange